# WebPart zone properties

Tags: web-part, css, web-part-zone

I used SharePoint Designer to insert the WebPart zone into page and the WebPart only covers %50 of the page, how can I make it to cover %100 of the page.

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="g_785AE8550D2848C981CDFD248A1B3EC8" runat="server" title="Zone 1"></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the complete code inside `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">` block? Are you using in custom CSS?

Comment: I can try, I am using insert web-part zone function in SharePoint designer

Comment: Put some code where you put webpart zone snippet and related css